# Upsert subdocuments then

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have an order object with an array of order items. Some of these items may not have been created yet so I would like to upsert the items, then add all of the items to the order. Below is what I am trying to do in my GraphQL resolver but I cannot chain `then` to `map`.

```
updateOrder: async (_, { order: { id, items, ...order } }, { req }) => {


        const updatedOrder = items
          .map(async ({ id, ...item }) => {
            await OrderItem.findByIdAndUpdate(
              id,
              { ...item },
              { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
            );
          })
          .then(
            async (res) =>
              await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
                id,
                { items: res, ...order },
                { new: true }
              )
          );

        return updatedOrder;
}
```

The result for the map does not resolve if used separately.

```
const updatedItems = items
          .map(async ({ id, ...item }) => {
            await OrderItem.findByIdAndUpdate(
              id,
              { ...item },
              { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
            );
          })

const updatedOrder = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
                id,
                { items: updatedItems, ...order },
                { new: true }
              )
          );
```

I think bulkWrite is what I need but I cannot figure out how to return the documents from the bulkWrite instead of the counts of modified documents. Without the new/updated documents, I don't know how to push them to the order.

Comment: Never read the word `upsert` until today. How weird.

Comment: promise.all, use search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .map with Promise.all to wait till all upsert's are completed and then finally update order. Second block of code can be updated to something like below:

```
const updatedItems = await Promise.all(
  items.map(async ({ id, ...item }) => {
    return OrderItem.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      { ...item },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
    );
  })
);

const updatedOrder = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
  id,
  { items: updatedItems, ...order },
  { new: true }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! For those who are doing something similar, I forgot to return from the map:

const updatedItems = await Promise.all(
  items.map(async ({ id, ...item }) => {
   return await OrderItem.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      { ...item },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
    );
  })
);

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Updated answer to return promise from map.